# Access navigation property when using Ajax in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I working with cascading dropdowns in .NET Core. It works correctly using Ajax.

Here is the code:

```
<td>
    <select id="productList" class="form-select" asp-items="@ViewBag.productItem">
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select id="colorId" >
    </select>
</td>

//Ajax

$(document).ready(function () {
    getProductByColor();
});

$("#productList").change(function () {
    getProductByColor();
});

function getProductByColor() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetProductByColor", "Invoice")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id : $('#productList').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#colorId').empty();
            $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                $('#colorId').append('<option value="' + item.colorId + '">' + item.color.colorName + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And the view of website will be like this:

[image]

But now I want show the Color Name not the Color Id. In my product items model, I have a `Color` property to navigate to Color model, so I can get the color name.

Here is the json return:

```
[
    {
        "productItemsId": 24,
        "productId": 1,
        "colorId": 1,
        "productCode": "AF1-White",
        "color": null,
        "product": null,
        "invoiceDetails": [],
        "ordersDetails": [],
        "productImages": [],
        "productVariations": [],
        "image1": null,
        "image2": null,
        "image3": null,
        "image4": null
    }
]
```

C# code:

```
public ProductItem()
{
}

public int ProductItemsId { get; set; }
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public int? ColorId { get; set; }
public string? ProductCode { get; set; }

public virtual Color? Color { get; set; }
```

I have tried to use the color property in Ajax but it didn't work

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#colorId').empty();
    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
        $('#colorId').append('<option value="' + item.colorId + '">' + item.Color.colorName + '</option>');
    });
}
```

Also use the include in `GetColorByProduct` method but still didn't work:

```
public JsonResult GetColorByProduct (int id)
{
    return Json(_context.ProductItems.Where(n=>n.ProductItemsId == id)
        .Include(n => n.Color)
        .ToList());    
}
```

Does anyone know the problem? I will appreciate any solutions. Many thanks

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the Network tab, what is the actual JSON returned from the server by this AJAX operation?

Comment: I just updated in the question @David

Comment: Hi John, it's a very simple issue. Please check the color properties in ajax success response. If you can make sure the color object is null, then we should set breakpoint in GetColorByProduct method, check if the `int id` enter this method or not. And also need to check the return data also in this method.

Comment: how can i make the GetColorByProduct method got the color object @JasonPan

Comment: Set breakpoint in this line `return Json(_context.ProductItems.Where(n=>n.ProductItemsId == id)`, and check the value of `int id`.